# Выравнивание временной метки при отображении таблицы голосов

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, дизайн

При отображении [таблицы голосов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut?tab=votes&sort=downvote) в профиле наблюдается нарушение выравнивания текста по горизонтали:

> [image: выравнивание поехало]

Видно, что пока указывается временной сдвиг (минуты, часы, дни), то всё хорошо. Но если начинает одновременно отображаться дата, то выравнивание столбца нарушается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текущий дизайн изменён и обозначенной проблемы не наблюдается:

> [image: Нет проблем]

Answer (score 1):

Дата имеет следующие стили

```
.user-show-new .history-table .date {
    text-align: center;
    ...
}
```

То есть, как я понимаю, дизайнеры задумывали выравнивание текста по центру. За счет разных форматов для дат, мы видим разные отступы.

Comment: Задумано может быть и [tag:так], но реализация-то кривая. И задумка по факту не работает.

Comment: @alexolut Мне кажется, я не до конца понял. Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Есть задумка: выровнять данные внутри столбца. И есть факт: данные внутри столбца не выровнены. Это ж просто кровь из глаз.

Comment: @alexolut. К дизайну тут вопросов нет (выравнивание идет по центру), а к переводу – есть. В англоязычной версии используется сокращенная версия, например, 1m, что в [нашем исполнении](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266627?key=cf70dc094064ba691fe0fe502fe8cf06%7C) будет 1 минута. Видимо, необходимо обратно короткий вариант.

Comment: Я уже упоминал как-то в другом ответе о том, что локализацию можно делать по-разному: либо подгонять перевод под оригинальный вариант (в данном случае уменьшить длину), либо обеспечить корректную работу при (почти) любой строке. Второй вариант сложнее, но он правильнее.